# How can I pass a viewmodel to a webapi method from a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a report to email to the user (since it takes some time to create.)  I am unable to call the web method and pass a viewmodel.

This is the WebApi controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace RecognitionsMVC.Controllers
{
    public class WebAPIController : ApiController
    {
        [ActionName("Post")]
        public static void GetAllRecognitionsBySupervisorAll([FromUri]ViewModels.AllRecognitionsbyAllSupervisors AllRByAllS)
        {
            DataSet ds = Classes.Recognitions.GetAllRecognitionsBySupervisorAll(AllRByAllS.BeginDate, AllRByAllS.EndDate, AllRByAllS.RecognizedOrSubmitted);
            Classes.DataHelper.SendMeExcelFile(ds, "GetAllRecognitionsBySupervisorAll", AllRByAllS.AuthenticatedUser);
        }

    }
}
```

This is the View Model I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RecognitionsMVC.ViewModels
{
    public class AllRecognitionsbyAllSupervisors
    {
        public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public string AuthenticatedUser { get; set; }
        public bool RecognizedOrSubmitted { get; set; }

        public AllRecognitionsbyAllSupervisors(DateTime BeginDate, DateTime EndDate, string AuthenticatedUser, bool RecognizedOrSubmitted)
        {
            this.BeginDate = BeginDate;
            this.EndDate = EndDate;
            this.AuthenticatedUser = AuthenticatedUser;
            this.RecognizedOrSubmitted = RecognizedOrSubmitted;
        }

    }

}
```

and this is the Test Controller I am trying to call the WebAPI controller and pass the view model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace RecognitionsMVC.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Test
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DateTime BeginDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
            DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(2015, 12, 31);
            string AuthenticatedUser = "123473306";
            bool RecognizedOrSubmitted = true;

            string VPath = "api/WebAPI/GetAllRecognitionsBySupervisorAll";
            ViewModels.AllRecognitionsbyAllSupervisors  AllRByAllS = new ViewModels.AllRecognitionsbyAllSupervisors(BeginDate, EndDate, AuthenticatedUser, RecognizedOrSubmitted);
            return View(VPath, AllRByAllS);

      }
    }
}
```

Finally this is the WebApiConfig.cs in the App_Start folder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace RecognitionsMVC
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: Add any additional configuration code.

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional , action = "DefaultAction"}
            );

            // WebAPI when dealing with JSON & JavaScript!
            // Setup json serialization to serialize classes to camel (std. Json format)
            var formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        }
    }
}
```

The error indicates the api cannot be found and appears to be looking in all the view folders and not the WebAPI controller.   How can I call the WebAPI method and pass a view model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Controller you can use a `HttpClient` to call the web api.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    // GET: Test
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        DateTime BeginDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
        DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(2015, 12, 31);
        string AuthenticatedUser = "123473306";
        bool RecognizedOrSubmitted = true;

        string VPath = "api/WebAPI/GetAllRecognitionsBySupervisorAll";
        ViewModels.AllRecognitionsbyAllSupervisors  AllRByAllS = new ViewModels.AllRecognitionsbyAllSupervisors(BeginDate, EndDate, AuthenticatedUser, RecognizedOrSubmitted);

        var baseUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:1234/");//Replace with api host address 
        var client = new HttpClient();//Use this to call web api
        client.BaseAddress = baseUrl;

        //post viewmodel to web api using this extension method
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(VPath, AllRByAllS);

        return View();

  }
}
```

Your Web Api would also needs to change to get the view model form the body.

```
public class WebAPIController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Post")]
    public static void GetAllRecognitionsBySupervisorAll([FromBody]ViewModels.AllRecognitionsbyAllSupervisors AllRByAllS)
    {
        DataSet ds = Classes.Recognitions.GetAllRecognitionsBySupervisorAll(AllRByAllS.BeginDate, AllRByAllS.EndDate, AllRByAllS.RecognizedOrSubmitted);
        Classes.DataHelper.SendMeExcelFile(ds, "GetAllRecognitionsBySupervisorAll", AllRByAllS.AuthenticatedUser);
    }

}
```

Comment: The "GetBaseURL" was unknown to the app.  (I'm a noob so I wasn't sure how to add that.  Also the AllRByAllS view model being passed indicates it cannot be converted to System.Net.Http.HttpContent.  I tried a convert but was not successful.  Any ideas on these two issues?

Comment: I found a GetBaseURL function which I added which appears to resolve the first issue.  Still not sure about the error converting to HttpContent from the List<ViewModel> object

Comment: `GetBaseURL` was just a placeholder Method that you need to implement yourself to get the host of you service. You could hard code that for testing. The `PostAsync` is a generic extension method for `HttpClient` in the  `System.Net.Http` namespace

Comment: Shouldn't a (relatively) expensive operation like a HTTP request be done in a service, and the service called from the controller? Not to mention it's better abstraction.

Comment: True this can all be abstracted away in a service. I was just showing you that it can be done.

Comment: In fact you should abstract the functionality you are trying to achieve out into a service and call that from the MVC controller but you specifically asked for how to send it to a web api which would mean over http

Comment: I was doing the web call mainly from old school asp.net methods that didn't have async and await functions.  I will try to move this to a service with await and async and avoid the webapi call.

Answer (score 1):

I think GetAllRecognitionsBySupervisorAll inside WebAPIController is not allowed to be static. When you mark it static it will not be found, so try removing "static".